# Are there any drawbacks to turning on ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Our database is currently running into blocking, deadlocking, and timeout issues that we are slowly starting to work through.  I came across the concept of snapshot isolation levels.  I don't think our app is ready for Read Comitted Snapshot enablement, but I do think that `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` being flipped on and certain problematic queries having the `set transaction isolation level snapshot` flag could be a huge help. There are all sorts of warnings about the need for testing when using read committed snapshot enablement and I understand why, but I just want to check and see if there if there are any concerns with turning on `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION`.  From my perspective there are none because nothing would magically swap to using snapshot isolation levels as is the case with read committed snapshot enablement.  It would only affect queries/sprocs/etc that we set the isolation level to snapshot going forward. Can anyone confirm or deny?

Comment: Once `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` is turned on, all data modifications will generate row versions. Additionally, 14-bytes overhead for modified rows.

Comment: That sounds like it could have big space impacts to space tempDB occupies and possible performance hits to the application?  Why would all data modifications generate row versions even if the query isn't using snapshot isolations?

Comment: Consider an `UPDATE` query that runs for several minutes. If you run a `SELECT` query in `SNAPSHOT` isolation while it's running, the version of the row before the update will be needed. I didn't mean to sound alarmist with my comment but you should be aware of the overhead and test with your workload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The drawbacks of turning on the `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` (or `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT`) database option is the additional overhead of maintaining row versions for all database transactions. The overhead includes maintaining the row version store in tempdb and an additional 14-bytes of storage per row. This overhead is detailed in [Row Versioning-based Isolation Levels in the Database Engine](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj856598(v=sql.110).aspx).

Even if you don't actually use `SNAPSHOT` isolation, SQL Server will still maintain row versions in a `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` enabled database in case a `SNAPSHOT` is started. The overall performance and storage impact of row versioning overhead depends much on your workload and environment. It's probably not so significant as to prevent you from using `SNAPSHOT` isolation and but you'll need to test to ascertain impact in your situation. There are certainly concurrency benefits that may offset the costs.

Answer (score 1):

It will eliminate all of your blocking between reads and writes. However blocking can still occur if two writes are happening at same time on same page. There is no way around that.

In my experience, the additional load because of Snapshot isolation(row versioning) is negligible and the benefits of row versioning in reducing blocked readers is huge.

Answer (score 1):

When snapshot isolation is enabled, old row versions are kept in tempdb until the transactions that could use them are finished. So if you have a transaction accidentally left open, tempdb can fill up until disaster happens.